# How can I swap parameters in string?

Tags: arrays, vim, swap

Text input example:

```
"The exponent of [i]*[i]*[i]*0,5 is [i*i*i*0.5]"|%d,%f,%d,%e
```

Text output must be:

```
"The exponent of [%d]*[%f]*[%d]*0,5 is [%e]"|i,i,i,i*i*i*0.5
```

What I did:
I tried first to put them in two arrays

```
array_text ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i*i*i*0.5']
array_parameters ['%d', '%f', '%d', '%e']
```

But I don't know how to switch `array_text[0]` in the text with `array_parameters[0]`,
`array_text[1]` in the text with `array_parameters[1]` and so on with the other array items.
How can I swap them in order to realize my text output as indicated above?

**Edit**:

I tried to resolve it like this:

```
   let end = 0
   for i in range(0,len(array_text)-1) 
    let idx = match(textstring, '\[\zs'.array_text[i], end)
         let end = matchend(textstring, array_text[i], idx)
         if end > idx
           let text = substitute(text, strpart(text, idx, end-idx), array_parameters[i], '')
         endif
    endfor
```

That seems to work but the substitute/strpart command doesn't work.

Comment: So, you're re-generating the output with the extracted elements of your two arrays, right? Wouldn't it be sufficient to swap the two array variables in that?!

Comment: I generated `array_text` removing all spaces between `][` and doing a substitute of `][` with `,` and split the string at the comma. How can I swap the two array variables?